# how to use different WHERE clause in left join

Tags: mysql, join, count, where-clause, group-by

I have two textfields, I posted each textfield value into MySQL query specially in WHERE CLAUSE.

```
$sWhere = " WHERE MONTH(Inspection_datetime) = '".$Month."' AND 
            YEAR(Inspection_datetime) = '".$Year."' ";
```

Then i tried to combine this query become like below:

```
$sQuery = "SELECT A.id,A.Line,
                  week1.1st, week2.2nd, week3.3rd, week4.4th, week5.5th,
                  IFNULL(week1.1st,0) + IFNULL(week2.2nd,0) + IFNULL(week3.3rd,0)
                + IFNULL(week4.4th,0) + IFNULL(week5.5th,0) AS Total
           FROM inspection_report AS A
           LEFT JOIN(
                     SELECT Line, (SUM(S) + SUM(A) + SUM(B)*0.4 +
                                   SUM(C)*0.1)/COUNT(Serial_number) AS 1st
                     FROM inspection_report
                     WHERE DAY(Inspection_datetime) BETWEEN 1 AND 7
                     GROUP BY Line, WEEK(Inspection_datetime),
                                    YEAR(Inspection_datetime)
                     ) AS week1 USING (Line)

                 LEFT JOIN(
                           SELECT Line, (SUM(S) + SUM(A) + SUM(B)*0.4 + SUM(C)*0.1)/COUNT(Serial_number) AS 2nd
                           FROM inspection_report
                           WHERE DAY(Inspection_datetime) BETWEEN 8 AND 14
                           GROUP BY Line, WEEK(Inspection_datetime), YEAR(Inspection_datetime)
                           ) AS week2 USING (Line)";
.........//SAME LIKE ABOVE JUST CHANGE INTO another week's range

$sWhere = " WHERE MONTH(Inspection_datetime) = '".$Month."' AND
           YEAR(Inspection_datetime) = '".$Year."' ";

$sGroupBy = " GROUP BY A.Line ";
$sQuery.= $sWhere.$sGroupBy;
```

i want it can counting data in weekly and also it can filtering by `$Month` and `$Year`.

But i got incorrect result. The result count data weekly for all month and all year.
How do i do to fix it?

Comment: You want to know why your query is wrong, or how you can get the results?

Comment: Remember [SQL Injection Attacks](http://xkcd.org/327).

Comment: actually i want to count data every week. Then sort them by selected Month and Year.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the `WHERE MONTH(Inspection_datetime) = '".$Month."' AND YEAR(Inspection_datetime) = '".$Year.` to every subquery

There are a couple things wrong with your current query:

1. You are joining the table by the `Line` field only, what you are telling MySql to do, is find the lines that have data for a month and year, and for those lines pull all their weekly data.
2. You are joining and grouping the tables multiple times (once for each week), is there a need for that? The query would be much quicker if you can get the weekly results by rows.
3. You are creating a new sub query for every 7 **days of the month**, but want to show the results by **week**

Comment: Actually i want to count data weekly in one month. so, i'm using BETWEEN 1 AND 7 and so on until we meet the 5th week. Whats the better way to get the correct result by using the correct query?